# On-topic here? "Should I contribute to a (kind of) abandoned project, or continue my own?"

Tags: discussion, scope

If this type of question is a good fit anywhere I suspect it's a better one here. Do you guys want it?

[Should I contribute to a (kind of) abandoned project, or continue my own?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/350202/should-i-contribute-to-a-kind-of-abandoned-project-or-continue-my-own)

Comment: No, that's entirely opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for whether it is on-topic, then yes!

It's a little bit opinion based, but I believe that the question is just fine. All questions need some degree of opinion to arrive to an expert answer - an opinion that may come from experience or other credible sources.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Was considering flagging it for transfer but our site has had so much trouble with having garbage dumped on it I thought the polite thing to do first was ask considering I don't have much experience here.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Oh thank you so much! Don't worry about flagging it - I trust the mods judgments on things, and even if they do migrate and it doesn't fit well here, we can just reject it. Aside from that though, thanks for the visit! We love seeing new people around here :)

Comment: Oops, already flagged it. Best way to get the mods attention. Included a link to this question. We've been hearing good things about you guys. Hope things go well.

Comment: Regardless of the merits of this question, it's nonsense to say that *all* questions need opinions to be answered.